# python 3.4: Cannot import class from another file

Tags: python, class, import

A question like this has appeared multiple times here, but none of the answers have worked for me. I'm using Python 3.4 with PyCharm as my IDE. In file `make_layers.py`, I have the following little placeholder of a class (`np` is my imported `numpy`):

```
class Finder:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_next_shape(self, uses_left):
        mask = np.zeros(uses_left.shape, dtype=np.int16)
        return mask
```

In another file in the same directory, `box_finder.py`, I try to import the class and make a subclass:

```
import make_layers as ml

class BoxFinder(ml.Finder):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

When I try to run this, it fails at the `import` statement, saying

```
AttributeError: module 'make_layers' has no attribute 'Finder'
```

I've tried endless variations on the syntax (including things like `from make_layers import Finder`), but nothing works. It must be something obvious, but I can't see the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

---

EDIT: Antti, you nailed it. There was a sneaky circular import in there. I moved `Finder` to its own file, and success! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your modules look correct, and should work.
The most likely source of error is that another file called `make_layers.py` is being imported. To check this, print `ml.__file__` to see where the `make_layers` module is being imported from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, to import your own `class`es you need to put them into your $PYTHONPATH environment variable.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/where/the/file/is
```

If this is the case i would suggest to put this line in your `.bashrc` to avoid doing the export in after every restart

Second, to make PyCharm recognise the importable classes from your script you have to mark the directory as `sources root`. After this PyCharm should see that you have a `Finder` class in`ml`